# Expand table width as screen resolution changes

Tags: html, css

How can I set the width of a table so it fits to the screen, even if the
screen resolution changes.

E.g. http://seemorgh.com/, as you see the black header in this site always fits to screen.

Comment: That header does not contain tabular data therefore it [shouldn't be a table in the first place](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi as per your question and refereed website according to that i think you don't need to define the width of the black header just define the background color and required height it will atomically adjust on user's screen size.....

Comment: Hi,now i have fix the width=980 for table but how can i do that it be automatically ?

Comment: see the example :- http://jsfiddle.net/LaKgG/19/

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking and what you want may be two different things.

### Header Bar from Site Example

From what I can tell by the example site you posted a link for, the header does not actually change width at all, but a black background band is set behind the header to fill the space to the sides on a wide screen.

This is actually done by having a structure like in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/LaKgG/15/).

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        Some content.
    </div>    
</div>

.outer {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}

.inner {
    width: 300px; /*some fixed or percentage width*/
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

### Make Table 100% Width

Now, as far as actually making a `table` element always fill the screen, that is not too difficult.

```
table {width: 100%}
```

When the screen becomes very narrow, it does have a practical limit and forces a horizontal scroll bar depending on table content. Some media queries can alleviate this for modern browsers (IE9+). [Play around with resizing this table](http://jsfiddle.net/LaKgG/11/) which has these media queries to help keep even small space filling just the full screen (but even that, as you see with the text size, has a practical limit to what one would really want to implement):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  table {font-size: 70%;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 250px) {
  table {font-size: 50%;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 150px) {
  table {font-size: 30%;}
}
```

Comment: ,thanks but i have a table in header which is contained some php codes and i put table {width: 100%} in my css file and then in table i set class="table" but it is still fix' ofcource the table has one row and 2 cols.

Answer (score 0):

table itself is a HTML tag and you need not mention class="table" in your page. It's enough you just mention the basic HTML tag which is table

For example

```
    table {width:100%;}

    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Sample One</td>
    <td>Sample Two</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```